# Scala map cannot resolve mapper function

Tags: scala, dictionary, higher-order-functions

Scala noob here.

I'm trying to apply a map in a class method:

```
class Miner(args: Args) extends Job(args) {

  def fetchUrl(url:String) = {
    ...
  }

  TextLine(args("input")).map(url: String => fetchUrl(url))
    .write(args("output"))
}
```

this codes breaks complaining about not being able to resolve the symbol `fetchUrl`.

I've thought that, fetchUrl being a one argument function, I could just omit the argument and do something like:

```
  TextLine(args("input")).map(fetchUrl)
    .write(args("output"))
```

This now breaks saying that I'm missing arguments for the method `fetchUrl`.

What gives?

Comment: What is the definition of `mapTo`? Can you post the exact error message you are seeing?

Comment: Typo in the question. I'm in fact using `map`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't `mapTo` a **curried** function?

I imagine you use this function from [this](http://twitter.github.io/scalding/com/twitter/scalding/TextLine.html) object:  (google redirects me to that)

`mapTo[U](out: Fields)(mf: (String) ⇒ U)(implicit flowDef: FlowDef, mode: Mode, setter: TupleSetter[U]): Pipe`

Perhaps you would use it like this: `Textline.mapTo(args("input"))(fetchUrl)`

You have some examples of `mapTo` usage at this page, but based on the `Pipe` object:
https://github.com/twitter/scalding/wiki/Fields-based-API-Reference#map-functions

Excerpt:

```
val savings =
  items.mapTo(('price, 'discountedPrice) -> 'savings) {
    x : (Float, Float) =>
    val (price, discountedPrice) = x
    price - discountedPrice
  }
```

So not based on `TextLine` in this example, but also curried...this might be a good hint for you.

Comment: I was trying to use `map` actually. The compiler complains about `mapTo` not being member of `TextLine` which weird because it is. Traceback here: http://linkode.org/H0mL92wMR5VsbFAodsQ5l6

Comment: @tutuca Do you use an IDE? Even suggestion (autocomplete) is not shown up?

Comment: Intellij in fact. But the function signature of `map` makes no sense to me (remember the noob part?). I get now that the argument to the `map` are the fields from the `TextLine` object and the curly braces part is a sort of anonymous function call, no?

Comment: Linkode's Scala highlighting kind of sucks: http://linkode.org/BshBK6mdZR1Utzmj5LIIK4 . Note that I've changed the syntax and now kind of works. It's still complaining that fetchUrl got a `symbol` (`'url`)...

Comment: Actually, you didn't provide a value for the map, that explains why your code didn't compile.                     Based on the API reference: https://github.com/twitter/scalding/wiki/Fields-based-API-Reference#map-functions              Try this: http://linkode.org/BshBK6mdZR1Utzmj5LIIK4/f80Ubq92NME2tYwGkFUkL

Comment: Updated: http://linkode.org/BshBK6mdZR1Utzmj5LIIK4/mdyhts97fbI5ashFe9WCf. Forgot to specify the last argument as being a function literal.

Comment: @Mik378... I swear that I don't understand what is happening there... Is `'fetchedUrl` some kind of output? I thought that those arguments where some kind of schema for `TextLine`'s items. What does `url => fetchUrl(url)` means? "call the next anonymous function with this parameter (url)"?

Comment: Small improvement... Your last update sort of works, but now it complains about type mismatch: http://linkode.org/BshBK6mdZR1Utzmj5LIIK4/isybkRxnuWrsio2u5DBeZ2.

Thanks for the helping hand man!

Comment: `map('1 -> '2)(number => number + 1)` means: "I already have an entry whose key is `'1'` in my map. Based on its value, I want to add a `'2` which has the same value of `'1`'s value incremented by 1. Here, number is the value of `'1`'s value.  It might be weird, but this is how this API works. Thus the last argument is a function literal in order to provide the needed transformation based on `'1` value to `'2`'s value

Comment: Concerning the compile error, try out replacing this line: `.write(args("output"))` by this line: `.write(Tsv(args("output")))`  I'm pointing out that I never used this API so you might need another type of `Source`.

Comment: Ah, you are right about that. That last bit got missing in due to the edits I've been doing...